# Android : execute() method of AsyncTask cannot be applied. Why?

Tags: java, android

The code :

```
attemptLogin.execute(editName.getText().toString(),editPassword.getText(),"");
```

There is an error on the above line.

The code for AsyncTask is as follows :

```
private class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

@override
```

There is an error on the override too.

Comment: i don't see any error on the above line or on the override too

Comment: can you please post your complete code

Comment: I think you must add toString() on editPassword.getText() as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `@override` with `@Override`.

Also replace `attemptLogin.execute(editName.getText().toString(),editPassword.getText(),"");` with `attemptLogin.execute(editName.getText().toString(),editPassword.getText().toString(), obj);`

**Note : In the third parameter, the obj should be of type "JSONObject". Please do send it as a parameter. Replace "" by JSONObject instance.**

Comment: Thanks i fixed the issue and all the other errors but there is a new error now about ArrayList